# Bokeh2 Effect Pass

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to move the Bokeh2 Depth of Field effect into an effect composer pass.
When I run it I'm getting the error:

glDrawElements: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same.

Here is the render function:

```
render: function ( renderer, writeBuffer, readBuffer, delta, maskActive ) {

    renderer.clear();

    // Render scene into texture

    this.scene.overrideMaterial = null;
    renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera, this.rtTextureColor, true );

    // Render depth into texture

    this.scene.overrideMaterial = this.material_depth;
    renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera, this.rtTextureDepth, true );

    // Render bokeh composite

    renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had confused the actual scene with the scene that is created by the DOF effect. This meant that I was trying to read from and write to the same buffer on the first render call.
To fix I had to pass in the original scene and camera and use that to generate the color and depth buffers.

```
renderer.render( this.originalScene, this.originalCamera, this.rtTextureColor, true );
```

etc.
Then render the effect scene after using the generated textures